# HttpClientFactory and WebAssembly .Net core hosted crashes on on client

Tags: json, asp.net-core, .net-core, blazor, webassembly

I am looking to call external webservice from a Blazor WebAssembly which is also ASP.Net Core hosted.

Couple of background information

1. A lot of this is based on Tim Corey's video on HtmlClient in normal Blazor Server which works find.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cwgck1k0YKU

2. Microsoft has documentation on adding client,  but so far when it called sendasync it exits

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/blazor/webassembly/additional-scenarios?view=aspnetcore-3.1

the following is some code for what is being attempted. I am new to Blazor and love it.

Update: 06/11/2020
I have created a GitHub example - with this problem included - it actually a little more because it allows multiple ASP.Net Code Host to be used but only works if 2nd host is passed through the original host

https://github.com/HStewartGitHome/BlazorMultiServer

Stewart

```
public static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    string uri = "https://www.metaweather.com/api/";
    var builder = WebAssemblyHostBuilder.CreateDefault(args);
    builder.RootComponents.Add<App>("app");

    builder.Services.AddTransient(sp => new HttpClient { BaseAddress = new Uri(builder.HostEnvironment.BaseAddress) });

    builder.Services.AddHttpClient("ServerAPI",
                     client => client.BaseAddress = new Uri(uri))
                    .AddHttpMessageHandler<BaseAddressAuthorizationMessageHandler>();

    builder.Services.AddTransient(sp => sp.GetRequiredService<IHttpClientFactory>()
                    .CreateClient("ServerAPI"));

    await builder.Build().RunAsync();
}

protected override async Task OnInitializedAsync()
{
    var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get,
        "location/2471217/");

    var client = _clientFactory.CreateClient("ServerAPI");

    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.SendAsync(request);

    if (response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        forecast = await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<WeatherForecastModel>();
        errorString = null;
    }
    else
    {
        errorString = $"There was an error getting our forecast: { response.ReasonPhrase }";

    }
}
```

Comment: So location is the controller, right ? and what exactly is 2471217

Comment: Did you check the server response ? Is it return json or an unauthorized page ? Can you post the console and network log ?

Comment: This is a rather complicated idea with multiple servers - I  am most done with GitHub example - unfortunately when I debug it - the call for sending response bombs. It works from normal server calls only on Blazor Webassembly  razor page.

Comment: I updated text issue and included a link for GitHub example

Comment: It is important to note this is in client code and not not the server code. The same problem even happens when executing a simple javascript.  This might not be important and it maybe best to use the Host servers to call others service API's  I believe that is was aqua from mars site does

Comment: System.Net.Http.HttpRequestException: No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
 ---> System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (10061): No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it.
   at System.Net.Http.ConnectHelper.ConnectAsync(String host, Int32 port, CancellationToken cancellationToken)

Comment: I've got exactly the same issue - was this ever resolved?